# What is wrong with this android code?

Tags: android

When I try to run this code I get an error in the view activity stating that void is an invalid type for the function "protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)".

### This is the main activity

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CrazyEightsActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CrazyEightsView myView = new CrazyEightsView(this);
    setContentView(myView);
}
}
```

### This is the View activity

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class CrazyEightsView extends View
{
private Paint redPaint;
private int circleX;
private int circleY;
private float radius;

public CrazyEightsView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circleX = 100;
    circleY = 100;
    radius = 30;
```

### This is where the error occurs.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move onDraw out of the constructor.

```
public CrazyEightsView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circleX = 100;
    circleY = 100;
    radius = 30;
} // <-- put } here

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
}

//}  <-- used to be here
```